# Highcharts: Rendering Incorrectly Prices between Percent/Value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Good morning everyone, hope you are doing well.

I am developing a Vue.js component with a chart from the Highcharts library implemented and I came across a problem where percent chart renders correctly based on my series, but value charts are not, for the same series. Specifically on my values chart my chart does not start from the correct date (or it might do  but x axis overlap the price). Let me provide some pictures to be more helpful:

---

My Prices:

[image]

---

My performance chart that **renders correctly** (it starts from the begging of the xAxis as the first value the starting point)

[image]

---

This is my values chart that does **NOT** render correctly. It should start from the timestamp of prices[0] **(24 of June)** (which is prices[0][0]) and have the value of that timestamp (prices[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHt3m.png)) which is 348.77.

[image]

---

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Does this problem also occur in JSFiddle? If so, it will be much easier if you could send me your code, so that I can also test it. Here you can find a basic template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jvry05wb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, I just did set the wrong min value on the valuesChart.